# Can i take the wms url from the user interface

Tags: javascript, wms, openlayers, url

If user wants to overlay his own wms layer overlay on the basemap of our portal, then how can user pass that url to openlayers method like below code enter code here

```
        overlayGroup.getLayers().push(new ol.layer.Tile({
        title: 'Africa Major Crop Lands',
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: '',
        params: {'LAYERS': ''},
        serverType: 'geoserver'
        })
        }));
        overlayGroup.getLayers().push(new ol.layer.Tile({
        title: 'South Asia Crop Intensity',
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: '',
        params: {'LAYERS': ''},
        serverType: 'geoserver'
        })
        }));
```

For this code I want to pass url and LAYERS from user side like below[image: example]

[image: Desired][image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you have a look at this Example: [WMS](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-tiled.html?q=WMS)

Note the following code:

```
new ol.layer.Tile({
      extent: [-13884991, 2870341, -7455066, 6338219],
      source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'http://demo.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/wms',
        params: {'LAYERS': 'topp:states', 'TILED': true},
        serverType: 'geoserver'
      })
    })
```

Out of these parameters, you need to provide the `url` and the `LAYERS` variables. The others are optional.

Ofcouse this sample assumes that your WMS server can provide images in the Coordinate System that your map is in

Comment: sir i want to pass url and layer name dynamically from user interface

Comment: like external web map service in that case user will pass his own geoserver's wms url and layer name visit link http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/cascaded/wms.html

Comment: visit http://bhuvan.nrsc.gov.in/map/bhuvan/bhuvan2d.php#  in that portal in tool button its giving option like add layer in that user can  overlay their own kml,shape file,wms layers overlay

Comment: tools-->add layer-->wms layer

Comment: So this was an example of what parameters you would need. Your JavaScript Code would take the values from the form, create a new layer with these parameters, and then add it to map.

Comment: can you refer any basic examples or jsfiddles for my practice

Comment: sir i have seen the link visit [1]: https://books.google.co.in/books?id=XgccDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA53&lpg=PA53&dq=ol.layer.tile+example+with+dynamic+url&source=bl&ots=tx693xnAvl&sig=L-5Kf19ZwLdv7BYoJ-HcZEHM9ow&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8hL_5rsrNAhVFO48KHUy-Bkk4ChDoAQgmMAI#v=onepage&q=ol.layer.tile%20example%20with%20dynamic%20url&f=false as Adding WMS Layer

Comment: Why they are using request.open('GET','../../../cgi-bin/proxy.py?'+encodeURIComponent{url},true};

Comment: i have seen url=/\?/.test{url} ? url + '&' : url + '?';

Comment: If it is geoserver who the URL will be i can you suggest any sample code for it please.